# ggplot piechart label freq instead of percent?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi supposed I have the following pie info.

```
df=structure(list(Var1 = c("a", "b"), Freq = c(306L, 1064L), per = c(0.223357664233577, 
0.776642335766423)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I plot this pie chart with direction -1

```
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = "", y = per, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(per, accuracy = 1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color = "grey20", size = pietext ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", direction =-1 ) +
  theme_void ()
```

However what I would like is to label with with the frequency rather than the percentage.

```
  Var1 Freq       per
1    a  306 0.2233577
2    b 1064 0.7766423
```

[image]
Is this possible with this method? I tried replacing per with Freq but that just gave some really strange text.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aes(label = Freq) is the way to go:

```
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = "", y = per, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color = "grey20", size=12) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", direction =-1) +
  theme_void ()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change  `geom_text(aes(label =Freq)`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = per, fill = Var1)) +
   geom_col() +
   geom_text(aes(label =Freq),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color = "black", size = 10 ) +
   labs( x="", y="", fill="")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4E79A7", "#fc7d0b"))+
  coord_polar(theta = "y", direction =-1 ) +
  theme_no_axes()
```

Plot:

[image]

or something that is better than a pie chart

Sample code:

```
library(waffle)
library(ggthemes)

    vals <- c(306,1064)
    val_names <- sprintf("%s (%s)", c("a","b"), label=vals)
    names(vals) <- val_names
    
    waffle::waffle(vals) +
    ggthemes::scale_fill_tableau(name=NULL)
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample code:

```
df=structure(list(Var1 = c("a", "b"), Freq = c(306L, 1064L), per = c(0.223357664233577, 0.776642335766423)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```